# Invalid cross-thread access using ReactiveUI RouterViewHost

Tags: routes, reactiveui

I am trying to learn ReactiveUI, and am currently trying to set up the Routing feature.  I have been "following" the Play rxui-5-update branch on github:

https://github.com/play/play-windows/tree/rxui5-update/Play

In my MainWindow.xaml where I am setting up the RoutedViewHost I am getting the following error:

Invalid cross-thread access

...on the following line:

The same error is generated within MainWindow.xaml of the rxui5 version of Play.

Comment: Call stackkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: > System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.AsyncLock.Wait(System.Action action) + 0x202 bytes 
  System.Reactive.Linq.dll!System.Reactive.TailRecursiveSink<ReactiveUI.IObservedChange<object,object>>.Run.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Action self) + 0x65 bytes 
  System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Schedule.AnonymousMethod__45(System.Action<System.Action> _action, System.Action<System.Action<System.Action>> self) + 0x97 bytes

Comment: The runtime error is:

Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.

The design time error is: Invalid cross-thread access

Comment: Another difference between my example and the Play example is that I am loading Windows into my RoutingViewHost as opposed to UserControls as in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load Windows into a RoutingViewHost because it's a control. Load UserControls into the RoutingViewHost and create a top-level window whose contents are just a RoutingViewHost

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks Paul, Routing is now working.  Now to include the message bus!

Comment: You really should avoid the message bus at all costs - it's a sign of bad design; using WhenAny to reach into child objects is usually better